# IO Exception while accessing Google Cloud message?

Tags: android, http, google-cloud-messaging

I have written the code for GCM both in server and Android. I am getting the Registration ID successfully.But I am not able to register to GCM,while making a post to register it shows an IO exception.I have used [Android hive tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) for this.I have gmail id and registration id with me and also created a Url to post.Any idea please share with me.Thanks in advance

Comment: show us a stacktrace :)

Comment: @DanielSmith Pls see the stacktrace.And I have also used the google sample code from sample project

Answer (score 0):

These are the line of code that creates the exception:

```
int status = conn.getResponseCode();
if (status != 200) {
   throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
```

Basically this methods is responsible for sending a POST request to the server. Have you configured the endpoint URL correctly in the client app?

Edit: The status code 302 is "Found: The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI."
See here for more info: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true) , this code I have replaced with   GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationcontext(), true);And the log again changed to post failed with error 302.

Comment: I am guessing you are sending to a wrong server URL, could you just please verify that the URL you are sending to does not redirect the request. From the webpage I added in the answer, this is included: "If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued."