# GCM URL and 302 redirect response

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

My Question is regarding GCM URL and 302 redirect response.

When I do `curl -v url = https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`, I get a `302` response with a new URL populated in location header. My question is, why can't I use the new URL received in 302 redirect always? What is the reason for Google responding with 302 redirect? I would really appreciate detailed explanation.

Many Thanks,
Sushil

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#302_Found), error 302 means *"Resource temporarily located elsewhere according to the **Location** header."* This seems to be a previously [reported issue](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/114) (with GCM):

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/WwEg6buc-K0
- [IO Exception while accessing Google Cloud message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037454/io-exception-while-accessing-google-cloud-message)

Suggested action is to re-run the request to the provided (temporary, alternate) URL.